# $\lambda(x) = (x,f(x))$, $w = A\,dx + B\,dy$, then $\int_\lambda w = \int_a^b [A(x,f(x)) + B(x,f(x)), f'(x)] \ dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

> If the path $\lambda:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is the graph of a function
>   $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ of class $C^1$, that is, $\lambda(x) =
>  (x,f(x))$ and $w = A\,dx + B\,dy$ is a $1$-form defined in a set that contains the image
>   of $\lambda$, then:
>
> $$\int_\lambda w = \int_a^b [A(x,f(x)) + B(x,f(x)), f'(x)] \ dx$$

By the Stieltjes integral definition along a path:

$$\int_\lambda w = \lim_{|P|\to 0} \sum_i^k w(\lambda(\zeta_j)) \cdot [\lambda(t_j) - \lambda(t_{j-1})]$$

I know that $w(\lambda(\zeta_j)) = A(\lambda(\zeta_j)) \, dx + B(\lambda(\zeta_j)) \, dy = A(\zeta_j, f(\zeta_j)) \, dx + B(\zeta_j, f(\zeta_j)) \, dy$. I must take the dot product of this with $[\lambda(t_j)-\lambda(t_{j-1})]$... But I must prove a relation for a Riemann integral, so things are a little bit more complicated. Where did that $f'(x)$ came from and how did $dy$ disappear?

Comment: Why do you want to use Stieltjes integral definition? Do you know how to integrate a differential form up to the level of Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds or Munkres's Analysis on Manifolds?

Comment: $\int_\lambda g(x_1,x_2) dx_1 = \int_a^b g(\lambda(t)_1,\lambda(t)_2) \lambda'(t)_1 dt$. In your case $\lambda(t) = (t,f(t)), \lambda'(t) = (1,f'(t))$ and $\int_{\lambda}w =\int_\lambda A(x_1,x_2) dx_1 +\int_\lambda B(x_1,x_2) dx_2=\int_a^b A(t,f(t))dt+\int_a^b B(t,f(t))f'(t)dt$

Comment: @reuns you should make this an answer so I can give you the bounty